# Having trouble connecting to named pipe from a C++ win32 program

Tags: c#, c++, .net, winapi, named-pipes

I have two programs that run on the same computer and I need them to talk.  One is an existing program written in C++ using the older windows32 framework.  The other is a newly written C# application using the .NET framework.  My newer .NET application will act as the server and the older existing application the client.

I have the named pipe created on both the client and server.  I am just not able to get them to connect.  I suspect the problem is simply I am not matching the file name correctly (named pipes use files in the background).

Here is the .NET server code:

```
    private volatile NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer;
    pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("MyPipe", PipeDirection.InOut);
    pipeServer.WaitForConnection();
```

Here is the older existing win32 client code:

```
HANDLE pipe = CreateFile(
    "\\Device\\NamedPipe\\MyPipe",
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, // only need read access
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL
);
```

I run the server code first and it sits there waiting for a connection.  Every single time my handle is equal to `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.

I used ProcessExplorer to see if I can find the true name of the pipe.  According to ProcessExplorer the name is **\Device\NamedPipe\MyPipe**.

I think I am matching this on my client side.  If anyone can lend a suggestion I am appreciative.  Thanks.

Comment: The `\Device\NamedPipe\MyPipe` is the device path as seen by the kernel.  The Win32 subsystem uses a different syntax, as per Jerry's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To open a named pipe with `CreateFile`, you need to specify the file name as `\\.\pipe\name`, so in your case it would look like:

```
HANDLE pipe = CreateFile(
    "\\\\.\\Pipe\\MyPipe",
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, // only need read access
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL
);
```

Comment: Yes that was it.  I had originally tried this but using "pipe" rather than "Pipe" as the web example (http://www.avid-insight.co.uk/2012/03/introduction-to-win32-named-pipes-cpp/) I was following had shown.  In that example both apps were using win32 framework so it seems to have worked out.  My guess is that the .NET abstraction defaults to use an upper case "Pipe".  With the upper case name it works for me now.  I hope that helps others who might be struggling on this in the future.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `PipeSecurity` solved this issue for me. Making it accessible for `Everyone` looks less secure but it worked.

```
PipeSecurity ps = new PipeSecurity();
PipeAccessRule psRule = new PipeAccessRule(@"Everyone", PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);
ps.AddAccessRule(psRule);
 NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("datapipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, 1, 1, ps);
```

Source: [Named Pipe Error - System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6ce43c90-00da-47e6-8e8c-4fdb2f7cc13e/named-pipe-error-systemunauthorizedaccessexception-access-to-the-path-is-denied?forum=netfxnetcom)